# Attribute Error with Python Library VapourSynth

Tags: python, video-processing, vapoursynth

I've installed Python 3.7 and **Vapoursynth** library from this [link](https://github.com/vapoursynth/vapoursynth/releases).

Now I'm trying to open a `.mp4` video, but there's an attribute error:

```
 AttributeError: No attribute with the name lsmas exists. Did you mistype a plugin namespace?
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 2019, latest compiled FFMS2 and L-SMASH source plugins for VapourSynth for Windows,  by Wolfberry you can download from https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=176198

unzip those and put ffmsindex.exe, ffms2.dll and vslsmashsource.dll into your C:\Program Files (x86)\VapourSynth\plugins64 directory. Then , you can use these lines in your Vapoursynth scripts to load videos,

```
from vapoursynth import core
clip = core.ffms2.Source(videofile) #for mkv extensions
clip = core.lsmas.LibavSMASHSource(videofile) # for mp4, mov extensions
clip = core.lsmas.LWLibavSource(videofile)  #for ts, m2ts, mts
```

Answer (score 0):

VapourSynth provides only a core set of filters, mostly inside the namespaces "core", "resize" and "text". Additional filters can be downloaded from other sites, mostly from [Doom9](https://forum.doom9.org/forumdisplay.php?f=82) or with Myrsloiks [VSRepo](https://github.com/vapoursynth/vsrepo). These filters provide Python modules or additional filters accessible by namespaces provided by VapourSynth plugins.

To answer your questions directly: "lsmas" is provided by [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3i81ttxf028m1eh/AAABkQn4Y5w1k-toVhYLasmwa?dl=0) Plugin. This is the official dropbox download link provided by the author (as seen in his [doom9](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=167435) release post).

By downloading the plugin and placing it inside `<vapoursynth-install-path>/plugins32` or `<vapoursynth-install-path>/plugins64` depending on whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit installation of Python. [Refer to this page for more information.](http://www.vapoursynth.com/doc/autoloading.html#windows)

I hope this helps.